# SQL get character before and after '/'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DCR/170/06
DCR/001/07
DCR/1504/07
```

I want get the character between the '/' and then +1
my expected output as below:

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT('000'+CAST(Doc_Num+1 AS VARCHAR(4)),4)) AS NEW_RESULT FROM Dms_Table

171
002
1505
```

Comment: Have you looked at using the SQL SubString function? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [ParseName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)

```
Declare @String varchar(100) = 'DCR/170/06'

Select 1+ParseName(Replace(@String,'/','.'),2)
```

Returns

```
171
```

Comment: Nice! assuming this string is not containing `.`

Comment: @UV  Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
select cast(substring(doc_num, 5,
                      charindex('/', doc_num, 5)
                      ) as int) + 1
```

This particular version assumes that the `'DCR/'` is how all the strings start.

You seem to understand how to left pad the value with zeros.